# Botón para interactuar con la base de datos Mongo Atlas en Flask

Tags: python, bootstrap, mongodb, flask

Quiero agregar un botón en mi página que me actualice los datos que muestra la misma(cambiar un nombre, una cantidad, añadir x cosa...) y otro botón para que los elimine. Estoy utilizando Python, Flask y Bootstrap para el desarrollo, y MongoDB Atlas para la base de datos. He estado buscando ejemplos y documentación pero no termina de quedarme claro.

Gracias por la ayuda.

P.D: Si tenéis sugerencias para optimizar mi código son bienvenidas, todo sea por mejorar.

Edit: he estado haciendo pruebas y añadiendo cosas al código, sigue sin actualizar los cambios que realizo

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://karmaster:acm1ptcactm@cluster0-gsee8.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.Rol_test

@app.route('/')
def inicio():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/clases', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def clases():
    clases = db.clases.find().sort("name", 1)
    return render_template('clases.html', clases=clases)

@app.route('/razas')
def razas():
    razas = db.razas.find()
    return render_template('razas.html', razas=razas)

@app.route('/armaduras')
def armaduras():
    armors = db.armaduras.find()
    return render_template('armaduras.html', armors=armors)

@app.route('/armas')
def armas():
    weapons = db.armas.find()
    return render_template('armas.html', weapons=weapons)

@app.route('/items')
def items():
    items = db.items.find()
    return render_template('items.html', items=items)

@app.route('/subida')
def subida():
    name = request.args['name']
    description = request.args['descripcion']
    stat_bonus = request.args['stat_bonus']
    dice_pv = request.args['dados_pv']
    dice_pm = request.args['dados_pm']
    licencias = request.args['licencias']
    hab1 = request.args['hab1']

    db.clases.insert_one(
        {
            "name": name,
            "descripcion": description,
            "stat_bonus": stat_bonus,
            "dice_pv": dice_pv,
            "dice_pm": dice_pm,
            "licencias": licencias,
            "hab1": hab1
        }
    )
    return redirect('/clases')

@app.route('/update')
def update():
    name = request.args['name']
    description = request.args['descripcion']
    stat_bonus = request.args['stat_bonus']
    dice_pv = request.args['dados_pv']
    dice_pm = request.args['dados_pm']
    licencias = request.args['licencias']
    hab1 = request.args['hab1']

    db.clases.update_one(
        {
            "name": name,
            "descripcion": description,
            "stat_bonus": stat_bonus,
            "dice_pv": dice_pv,
            "dice_pm": dice_pm,
            "licencias": licencias,
            "hab1": hab1
        }
    )

    return redirect('/clases')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**clases.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content%}

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Clases de Final Fantasy</h2>

        A continuación se muestran las clases disponibles para la creación de personaje asi como sus modificadores y habilidades

        <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Nombre de la clase</th>
              <th>Descripción</th>
              <th>Stat bonus</th>
              <th>Dados de vida</th>
              <th>Dados de magia</th>
              <th>Licencias de clase</th>
              <th>Habilidades de clase</th>
              <th>Boton de update</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="searchable">
            <form action="/update" method="get">
                {% for class in clases %}
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{class['name']}}"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" value="{{class['description']}}"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="stat_bonus" value="{{class['stat_bonus']}}"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="dice_pv" value="{{class['dice_pv']}}"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="dice_pm" value="{{class['dice_pm']}}"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="licencias" value="{{class['licencias']}}"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="hab1" value="{{class['hab1']}}"></td>
                        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button></td>

                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </form>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **PROBLEMA**

El problema es (*siempre lo es*)  que hace falta leer la [documentación](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one).

En tu método `update()`, estás pasando un único parámetro a la función `update_one` de *mongopy*:

```py
@app.route('/update')
def update():
    # ...
    db.clases.update_one({ "name": name, ... "hab1": hab1 })
    #...
```

Pero la documentación indica que esta función recibe al menos 2 parámetros:

- `filter`: una consulta (*query*) que coincida con algún algún documento de tu colección.
- `update`: las modificaciones que vas a aplicar

Si te fijas, tu sólo estás pasando un objeto:

```py
db.clases.update_one(
    {
        "name": name,
        "descripcion": description,
        "stat_bonus": stat_bonus,
        "dice_pv": dice_pv,
        "dice_pm": dice_pm,
        "licencias": licencias,
        "hab1": hab1
    }
)
```

Por lo tanto *pymongo* asume que el mismo es el filtro, y realiza la búsqueda de acuerdo a ese filtro.

Es muy probable que la búsqueda no proporcione resultados, ya que en teoría y por lo que ve de tu código, ese objeto representa para ti las modificaciones a realizar sobre el documento.

Suponiendo que la búsqueda usando dicho filtro arroje un resultado, *pymongo* aplicará la actualización sobre el mismo, pero dado que no proporcionas una actualización (*el argumento es `None` por defecto*), *pymongo* no realiza ninguna actualización, ya que no tiene nada para actualizar.

Otro problema que veo en tu planteamiento es la forma en la que muestras la plantilla para realizar modificaciones. Eso ya es un problema diferente al que planteas aquí, pero que en conjunto va todo relacionado, ya que si la lógica del programa está mal, el resultado no será el esperado.

### **SOLUCIÓN**

Intentaré abordar la posible solución (*digo posible porque hay más de una*) tratando de abarcar parte de tu problema global, que va más allá de cualquier lenguaje de programación.

**VERBOS INDICAN ACCIÓN, RUTAS INDICAN SUJETOS**

En casi todas las API REST para web te vas a encontrar un patrón muy utilizado, y es que no debes mezclar rutas (*endpoints*) con acciones.

El protocolo HTTP nos da todo lo que necesitamos para realizar operaciones [CRUD](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) sobre modelos de datos (sujeto).

Tus rutas deberían apuntar en todo caso a modelos de datos, y las operaciones (CRUD) sobre dichos modelos deben ser manejadas a través de los [métodos HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) bien conocidos:

- `POST`: Para la operación de creación (CREATE).
- `GET`: Para la operación de lectura (READ).
- `PUT`: Para la operación de actualización (UPDATE).
- `DELETE`: Para la operación de eliminación (DELETE).

Dicho esto, tus rutas no deberían ser las que indiquen una acción, por ejemplo:

```
@app.route('/update')
```

Esta ruta claramente no es la adecuada, porque a simple vista la primera pregunta que se me ocurre es: ¿Qué estoy actualizando?. Si luego necesito actualizar otra entidad, ¿cómo se lo indico al enviar datos a dicha ruta?

Y es que así vamos complicando la lógica de nuestro programa.

***UN ID PARA GOBERNARLOS A TODOS. UN ID PARA ENCONTRARLOS,
UN ID PARA ATRAERLOS A TODOS...***[1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anillo_%C3%9Anico#CITAREFTolkien)

Uno de los aspectos más importantes a la hora de trabajar con datos, es la unicidad de los mismos, de esta forma podemos realizar operaciones CRUD sobre un conjunto de datos o sobre un dato particular.

MongoDB nos provee el campo `_id` sobre cada documento almacenado en la base de datos, por lo tanto podemos rápidamente encontrar un documento usando la búsqueda mediante el campo `_id` que se garantiza único para cada documento.

A veces necesitamos actualizar documentos que comparten una característica en común, sin importar que los mismos sean diferentes entres si.

Para el caso que planteas, deseamos actualizar un documento en particular. Y has optado por usar la función o método `update_one` de *pymongo*.

Esta forma de realizar la actualización tiene algunos inconvenientes.

Imagina que en tu colección existe más de un documento cuyo campo `name` es `'Jonathan'`.

Digamos que hay 3 documentos:

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
    name: "Jonathan",
    lastname: "Wayne",
    abilities: ["millionaire", "inventor", "serious guy"],
    team: "DC Comic"
}, 

{
    _id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439012"),
    name: "Jonathan",
    lastname: "Stark",
    abilities: ["millionaire", "inventor", "sarcastic guy"],
    team: "Marvel"
},

{
    _id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439013"),
    name: "Jonathan",
    lastname: "Banner",
    abilities: ["scientist", "brute force", "very angry guy"],
    team: "Marvel"
}
```

Si deseara actualizar las habilidades de *Jonnathan Stark* por ejemplo, y basara mi búsqueda sólo en el nombre, podría no estar actualizando el registro correcto, ya que el motor de MongoDB no me garantiza una búsqueda secuencial de datos, se basa en índices y puede recorrer la colección de atrás hacia adelante, o en cualquier otro tipo de ordenamiento. Por lo tanto, el primer documento que coincida con la consulta será devuelto en la búsqueda y sobre el mismo se hará la actualización. Así, podría estar actualizando a *Jonathan Wayne* con un traje de *Hierro* que tal vez no vaya a juego con su *bati-cinturón*.

Sin embargo, si basamos la búsqueda sobre el campo `_id`, estaremos seguros de que al encontrar un documento en la colección, este será el que realmente estamos buscando, ya que el campo `_id` es único por documento.

Para actualizar el documento que requieres, necesitas poder identificarlo, y para ello necesitas conocer su valor de `_id` por ejemplo, o cualquier otro valor que sea único para el documento. En el ejemplo que puse, es probable que la combinación de nombres y apellidos sea única, por lo tanto nuestro filtro podría ser esa combinación:

```py
def update():
    filter = {
        "name":     name,
        "lastname": lastname
    }

    update = {
        $addToSet: {
            "abilities": ability
        }
    }

    db.superheroes.update_one(filter, update)

    #...
```

En tu pregunta y según se aprecia en el código, al parecer todos los campos de un documento de tipo `clase` se pueden modificar, por lo tanto mi sugerencia es que identifiques cada documento por su campo `_id`, de esta forma te aseguras de estar siempre actualizando el documento adecuado.

Una forma de implementar las rutas de actualización y otras operaciones CRUD sobre tus documentos sería la siguiente: (usaré como ejemplo el modelo de `clase`)

```py
# Ruta para listar todas las clases, sólo acepta métodos GET y POST
# Usando GET obtenemos la lista de todas las clases, usando POST creamos una nueva
@app.route('/clases', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#...

# Ruta para listar una clase particular, acepta GET, PUT, DELETE
# Usando GET obtenemos el detalle de la clase, PUT para modificar y DELETE para borrar
# Nótese que usamos un parámetro en la ruta: el identificador de la clase
@app.route('/clases/<id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE')
#...
```

Flask utiliza el valor pasado dinámicamente en la URL, por ejemplo: `/clases/507f1f77bcf86cd799439011` hará que la variable `id` tenga como valor: `507f1f77bcf86cd799439011`.

De esta forma podremos luego crear una consulta usando dicho valor como filtro:

```
filter = { "_id": id}
```

Con esto ya tenemos una forma de identificar la clase a la que queremos actualizar.

Un ejemplo aplicado a la colección de súper héroes sería:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

# Ruta para actualizar un super heroe
@app.route('/superheroes/<id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def super_hero_crud():
    filter = { "_id": id }
    operation = ''
    if request.method === 'GET':
        heroe = db.superheroes.find_one(filter)
        operation = 'read'
    elif request.method === 'PUT':
        update = {
            $addToSet: {
                "abilities": ability
            }
        }
        hero = db.superheroes.update_one(filter, update)
        operation = 'update'
    else:
        hero = db.superheroes.delete_one(filter)
        operation = 'delete'

    return render_template('hero.html', hero=hero, opration=operation)
```

Esto sería una forma básica de realizar operaciones CRUD sobre un documento de tu base de datos.

**Nota:**

Toda operación que realices sobre la base de datos debes hacerla dentro de un bloque `try / except` ya que debes capturar las excepciones relacionadas con los posibles errores al realizar dichas operaciones.

Por último, para enviar los diferentes métodos desde un formulario basta con usar el atributo [`method`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/form#Atributos) del mismo, por ejemplo en tu código puedes usar:

```
<form action="/clases/{{class['_id']}}" method="PUT">
```

para actualizar una clase.